# :onhover pseudo-class not working as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, css-specificity, onhover

I have a piece of code I've written, which I have placed above a section of minified CSS:

```
.scroll-fixed-navbar {
  background-color: black !important;
}

.banner-list li i {
  color: #f86900 !important;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #f86900 !important;
}

#nav li a {
  color: #f1861d !important;
}

#nav li:hover {
  color: #a8a89b !important;
}

[Huge chuck of minified code containing Font Awesome and Twitter Bootstrap]
```

On one server this works as expected, and the link items fade to grey on hover. On another server, however, the on hover effect does not trigger. I've tried opening the `li` elements in the inspector, but even on the server where the effect is working, the CSS doesn't appear to show up:

[image: On Hover bug screenshot]

I saw somewhere that the `:hover` pseudo-class should only be applied to the `a` element, but I looked at the W3C wiki, and there is no mention of this there. Can I apply `:hover` to the `li` parent of an anchor in this way, or is it illegal code? Might the Bootstrap and/or Font Awesome code be overriding the CSS? Or is the problem likely to be caused by something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this:

```
#nav li a {
  color: #f1861d !important;
}
```

is overriding this:

```
#nav li:hover {
  color: #a8a89b !important;
}
```

Why do you set the `:hover` on the `li`? Try targeting the `a` element after the `li:hover`:

```
 #nav li:hover a {
  color: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: This of course, works only if the `a` is the only child of the `li`. If it's not you need to set the other element's color as well. You could set the color on the li and then use color: inherit; on all the children.

Comment: Ok. It'll take a while to test, as I'll have to send the file to someone else along with some other changes for them to upload onto the production server. I think I changed to `li:hover` because for some reason  at the time `li a:hover` wasn't working at all on my test server, and I wanted to see if `li:hover` would, though as I recall that wasn't the fix. Anyway, this seems like a plausible explanation. Once it's tested I'll accept your answer if it works :).

Comment: I could never be quite sure if this was the problem or not, because I didn't have direct access to the production server to test, but it certainly seems to have been, so I've accepted the answer.